# Someone know how to prove the result 'a^b % m = (...((a % m) * a) % m) ......* a) % m' from mathematical view?

Tags: math, pow, modulo

Recently, I coded to realized **RSA algorithm**, I was confused by MOD-POWER problem, I couldn't why the equation is true, I can't give the proof of this equation:

```
'a^b % m = (...((a % m) * a) % m) ......* a) % m'
```

from mathematical view?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

From the basic things we know about multiplication in modular arithmetic.

We know that `(a * b) % m == ((a % m) * (b % m)) % m`

Answer (score 0):

As the power is defined recursively as

```
a^0 = 1,  a^b = a^(b-1) * a
```

you prove the modular formula also per induction, i.e., using

```
a^b % m = (  ( a^(b-1) % m ) * ( a % m )  )  %  m
```

as step.